# Check if all words first letter uppercase JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I get a boolean result in Js to check every words all first letter contains uppercase or not?

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

false

```
Lorem Ipsum Is Simply Dummy Text Of The Printing And Typesetting Industry.
```

true

```js
let wordArray = [];
let words = 'Lorem Ipsum Industry.';
var count = 0;

let wordsSplit = words.split(" ");
for(let i=0;i<wordsSplit.length;i++) {
  wordArray.push(wordsSplit[i]);
  if (wordsSplit[i].charAt(0).match(new RegExp(/^[A-Z]/)) !== null) {
    count++;
  }
}

if (wordsSplit.length == count) {
  console.log("all words contains first letter");
} else {
  console.log("false");
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you post your code?

Comment: ups, I forgot to add my method. Im just looking if there is a better way or not

Answer (score 0):

```js
const test1 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
const test2 = "Lorem Ipsum Is Simply Dummy Text Of The Printing And Typesetting Industry.";

function isEveryWordCapitalized(sentence) {
  return sentence.split(' ').every(word => {
      const firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
      return firstLetter.toUpperCase() === firstLetter;
  })
}

console.log(isEveryWordCapitalized(test1)); // false
console.log(isEveryWordCapitalized(test2)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RegEx:

```js
const test1 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
const test2 = "Lorem Ipsum Is Simply Dummy Text Of The Printing And Typesetting Industry.";

function hasOnlyInitialCapitalLatters(text) {
  if (typeof text !== "string") return console.error("only strings");
  const checkTinyLetterRegEx = new RegExp(/[a-z]/g);
  const textAsArray = text.split(" ");
  for(let word of textAsArray) {
    const firstLetter = word.charAt(0); 
    if(checkTinyLetterRegEx.test(firstLetter)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(hasOnlyInitialCapitalLatters(test1));
console.log(hasOnlyInitialCapitalLatters(test2));
```